# converting InetAddress to string

Tags: java, string, hashtable, inetaddress

Im using a hashtable to save filename (string) and InetAddress

```
Hashtable <String , InetAddress > file_location = new Hashtable <String , InetAddress >();
```

and im using this to retrieve the address, but im only getting a null value returned

```
file_location.put("ABD_9158" , IPAddress); //IPAdress is of InetAddress type

 InetAddress n = file_location.get("ABD_9158");

        System.out.println(n);
```

tried changing n to a string but , havent been able to find away 
my question, how do retrieve the ipaddress ?

Comment: you can run your program in debug mode and inspect the state of your map. If actually there is a key `ABD_9158` or any value corresponding to it.

Comment: @Amr Hamada try print your `HashMap`, `System.out.println(fileLocation );`

Comment: when i use enumerate e = file_location.key(); and print that, it returns ABD_9158

Comment: @ankur-singhal this is the output {ABD_9158=/192.168.2.21}

Comment: You have declared as fileLocation but used file_location afterwards. Hope this is not how the code is actually.

Comment: @Sachini nope its actually file_location through out my code, i didnt copy and paste, thats why i messed up

Comment: Also you need the new Hashtable initialization should end with `()`.

Comment: Assuming your IP address is not null because of a bug of the code somewhere else, it might be a good idea to use `String.valueOf(n)` because n is not actually a String. This is a good practise and I don't think is the actual error though

Comment: Ive figured it out, i had to tim();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a small program, to check what you want. Same piece of code, what you have shared, it is working fine.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hashtable<String, InetAddress> fileLocation = new Hashtable<String, InetAddress>();
        InetAddress addr;
        try {
            addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            fileLocation.put("ABD_9158", addr); // IPAdress is of InetAddress type
            InetAddress n = fileLocation.get("ABD_9158");
            System.out.println(n);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: yes actually when i used the the variable instead of "ABD_9158" i got the address return correctly , do u know why this might be happening. i am a hundred percent sure im writing correctly and matching it to the variable?

Comment: i compared both strings, the variable and the string "ABD_9158" and for some reason theyre not the same

Comment: @AmrHamada are you using `==` or `equals` to compare, the later will give you correct result, incase you are missing on that

Comment: no i was using `equals` when that didnt work i also used `equalsIgnoreCase`, if this helps im actually sending the file name through a datagram socket and recieving the file with this line `String file = new String( receivePacket.getData());`